# Set UICollectionView insets per row to center items with dynamic width

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I am trying to center items on a Collection View with dynamically sized items. I want to center those items, which in some cases can be one per row, and in some cases two. I found a solution to center items based on setting the inset of a section, but that requires that all items are the same size:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAtIndex section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets {

    let totalCellWidth = CellWidth * CellCount
    let totalSpacingWidth = CellSpacing * (CellCount - 1)

    let leftInset = (collectionViewWidth - CGFloat(totalCellWidth + totalSpacingWidth)) / 2
    let rightInset = leftInset

    return UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, leftInset, 0, rightInset)
}
```

This is an image of my collection view with 'justified' items, with dynamic spacing in between them:

[image]

My goal is to change the inset per row so the items are centered and the space between them is always the same.

Any idea on how I might be able to accomplish this?

Comment: Have you read about or used custom collectionView layout?

Comment: Isnt that what insetForSectionAtIndex does?

Comment: Nope. As the name suggests the `insetForSectionAtIndex` applies to the the entire section not individual item of that section. `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` is optimised for equally sized items. When you customise the layout you provide the layout attributes i.e. size and origin for each item of a section.

Comment: Perfect, that sounds about right. Can you point me out to any material on how to create a custom layout to define size and origin?

Answer (score 1):

As explained in the comments you'll have to use custom layout for your collectionView. To start with you can refer to the following links.

- https://octodev.net/custom-collectionviewlayout/
- https://www.raywenderlich.com/164608/uicollectionview-custom-layout-tutorial-pinterest-2
- https://www.netguru.co/codestories/practical-introduction-to-custom-uicollectionview-layouts

P.S: Since sharing just the links is not recommended here on stackoverflow so I'll update the answer asap and outline the basic steps required to use custom layouts.

Comment: Thanks, I'll keep posted to the edit so I can approve the answer